# Scapy Sniff() - Device Is A NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, packet-sniffers

So I'm trying to get scapy to work on my windows computer. After a lot of work I finally was able to load the library without any errors. However when I call the function `sniff(count=1)` I get an error. It seems that a variable called "device" is getting the value `None`. Here is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 445, in sniff
    s = L2socket(type=ETH_P_ALL, *arg, **karg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.ins = open_pcap(iface, 1600, self.promisc, 100)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 223, in <lambda>
    pcapdnet.open_pcap = lambda iface,*args,**kargs: _orig_open_pcap(pcap_name(iface),*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 251, in <lambda>
    open_pcap = lambda *args,**kargs: _PcapWrapper_pypcap(*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 215, in __init__
    self.iface = create_string_buffer(device.encode('ascii'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Thanks In Advance For Any Help :)

Comment: Show us your code.. Even if it's stupidly simple

Comment: I am literally just going into console and typing `from scapy.all import *` then typing `sniff(count=1)` @YotamSalmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the new development version and tinkering around with the timeouts of some of the powershell commands I fixed it! Guess it was just a bug with the old version. Scapy doesn't have the best Windows support.

Comment: Same Issue, what exactly did you do, can you recall? Feels like https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @Lex I beleive it was trying to call powershell but powershell wasnt in my enviorment variables. Also it would timeout too quick so somewhere I changed that. Sorry dont really remember too much. Hoped I helped

Comment: can you please tell us what you did to fix this ?